# Why should not use list.sort in python

Tags: python, sorting

While I was going through [Google Python Class Day 1 Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPYupizJYQI) at 14:20 - 14:30 Guy says *"do not use `list.sort`"*. Also he mentioned that *"Dinosaurs use that!"* (i.e. it's an old way of doing sorting). But he did not mention the reason.

Can anyone tell me why we should not use `list.sort`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `list.sort()` will do an in-place sorting. So this changes the original list. But `sorted(list)` would create a new list instead of modifying the original.

Example:

```
>>> s = [1,2,37,4]
>>> s.sort()
>>> s
[1, 2, 4, 37]
>>> s = [1,2,37,4,45]
>>> sorted(s)
[1, 2, 4, 37, 45]
>>> s
[1, 2, 37, 4, 45]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there any other disadvantage of using that?

Comment: @Laxmikant I don' t think doing a in-place sorting is a disadvantage, it is more efficient (according to python doc), and probably the only way to do it if you  have a very big list. One "real" disadvantage is that it is only defined for `list`, while `sorted` works on any `iterable`, so if one day you decide that you need to use something else than list, you'll be stuck :)

Comment: @Holt - Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 7):

I think it is very opinion based, sometimes you need to change an original list and you use *.sort()*, sometimes you don't need to change it, and you use *sorted()*

In general, **it isn't bad** to use .sort()

Answer (score 5):

From https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting:

> You can also use the `list.sort()` method of a list. It modifies the
>   list in-place (and returns `None` to avoid confusion). Usually it's less
>   convenient than `sorted()` - but if you don't need the original list,
>   it's slightly more efficient.

Many people prefer not changing the state of variables (look up the advantages of immutable values/data structures), and so would prefer not to modify the original list like `list.sort` does.

Comment: Surely people who preferred immutable data structures would be using a `tuple`, not a `list`?

Comment: Agreed, but you're using someone else's code and want to have minimal impact, it still holds true.